# Flex: flashVars via the <object> tag

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

with the following code:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="100%" height="100%" id="thisISparta">
            <param name="flashVars" value="asdf=GNU,is,not,unix" />
            <param name="movie" value="thisIsSparta.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
            </object>
```

How can i get the value of flash vars using Flex (flash builder 4.6) and without using swfObject.js?

With regards,

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the flashVars object using actionscript code like so:

In your main class:

```
loaderInfo.parameters
```

Or anywhere in your code (if your application is a Flex one)P

```
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters
```

The parameters property is an Object of key-value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly do you need ?

You can have php variables replacing the flashvars at runtime, or you can have them read from some other place.

Also you can have them in the url like

mysite.com/myswf.swf?asdf=GNU,is,not,unix&var2=value_of_var2

Comment: I think the OP is asking how to access the flashvars from *within* Flash using AS3, not how to pass them from the external context.